# How to properly use SUM and GROUP BY to demonstrate an invoice

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have been working on a project for my Introduction to Database class which uses oracle SQL.
I am having issues trying to get my output to show only one order number at a time.
I have to JOIN multiple tables to get the information needed.
is it possible to just use a WHERE statement like `WHERE o.order# = 10000001`?

```
SELECT 
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc AS "Product Description",
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  TO_CHAR(p.retail,  '$999.99') AS "Unit Price",
  TO_CHAR(SUM (p.retail * oi.order_qty),  '$9999.99') AS "Amount" 
FROM order_items oi 
JOIN products p ON oi.product# = p.product# 
JOIN orders o ON o.order# = oi.order# 
JOIN customers c ON c.customer# = o.customer# 
GROUP BY
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc,
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  p.retail
ORDER BY order#;
```

[image: Invoice1SO]

Comment: Sure, you can. What made you doubt it?

Comment: Please post your query, current and expected result as text. This tiny image is hard to read and the text it contains cannot be manipulated.

Comment: Here is my query from the picture

Comment: SELECT c.customer#, c.company_name, o.order#, oi.item#, p.product_desc AS "Product Description", p.product#, oi.order_qty,
TO_CHAR(p.retail, '$999.99') AS "Unit Price", TO_CHAR(SUM (retail*order_qty), '$9999.99') AS "Amount"
FROM order_items oi JOIN products p ON oi.product# = p.product#
JOIN orders o ON o.order# = oi.order#
JOIN customers c ON c.customer# = o.customer#
GROUP BY c.customer#, c.company_name, o.order#, oi.item#, p.product_desc, p.product#, oi.order_qty, p.retail
ORDER BY order#;

Comment: I don't know how I should write a query to show all the info but for only order# 10000001

Comment: And what keeps you from putting `WHERE o.order# = 10000001` in the query as you have suggested yourself?

Comment: I was putting the WHERE after GROUP BY which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc AS "Product Description",
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  TO_CHAR(p.retail,  '$999.99') AS "Unit Price",
  TO_CHAR(SUM (p.retail * oi.order_qty),  '$9999.99') AS "Amount" 
FROM order_items oi 
JOIN products p ON oi.product# = p.product# 
JOIN orders o ON o.order# = oi.order# 
JOIN customers c ON c.customer# = o.customer#
WHERE o.order# = '10000001'
GROUP BY
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc,
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  p.retail
ORDER BY order#;
```

you can add a WHERE statement after the last JOIN to filter.

Comment: Adding the WHERE statement after my last join gave me only order 10000001 which is what I needed. I much appreciate the help. Now I will have to try and figure out how to add all the Amounts for this one order to create a order total virtual column

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause goes before the GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc AS "Product Description",
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  TO_CHAR(p.retail,  '$999.99') AS "Unit Price",
  TO_CHAR(SUM (p.retail * oi.order_qty),  '$9999.99') AS "Amount" 
FROM order_items oi 
JOIN products p ON oi.product# = p.product# 
JOIN orders o ON o.order# = oi.order# 
JOIN customers c ON c.customer# = o.customer# 
WHERE o.order# = 10000001
GROUP BY
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  o.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc,
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  p.retail
ORDER BY order#;
```

Comment: Adding the WHERE statement after my last join gave me only order 10000001 which is what I needed. I much appreciate the help. Now I will have to try and figure out how to add all the Amounts for this one order to create a order total virtual column.

Answer (score 0):

This is no answer, but too long for a comment.

The `GROUP BY` and `SUM`in your query are completely pointless. As you group by order# and item# and quantity, an order would have to have the same item with the same amount listed twice, so you could sum the two up (while leaving other duplicates with different amounts as is). This makes no sense.

This leaves us with:

```
SELECT 
  c.customer#,
  c.company_name,
  oi.order#,
  oi.item#,
  p.product_desc AS "Product Description",
  p.product#,
  oi.order_qty,
  TO_CHAR(p.retail,  '$999.99') AS "Unit Price",
  TO_CHAR(p.retail * oi.order_qty,  '$9999.99') AS "Amount" 
FROM order_items oi 
JOIN products p ON oi.product# = p.product# 
JOIN orders o ON o.order# = oi.order# 
JOIN customers c ON c.customer# = o.customer#
WHERE o.order# = 10000001
ORDER BY oi.item#;
```

As to the data model: You should store the price in `order_items`. Otherwise, when changing an item's price some time, you'll have involuntarily changed your existing orders.

As to `TO_CHAR`: I would refrain from it. Let your app or Website handle the layout. It should know better than the DBMS (and you at design time) which local settings (e.g. which decimal separator) the user prefers. Show your app that it is dealing with a number, not a string.

Comment: This is a project I'm working on for my Introduction to Database final. We were instructed to use TO_CHAR for all of our monetary output but I totally get why you wouldn't in a real world situation.